# Looking for values in Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to memoize divisor sums of numbers.

```
divisorSums = {}

def sumDivisors(num):

    global divisorSums

    total = 0

    if num == 1:
        return 0

    for i in xrange(num/2, 0, -1):
        if i in divisorSums:
            return divisorSums[i]
        else:
            if not num % i:
                total += i

    divisorSums[num] = total

    return total
```

However, this returns 1 for all numbers, when I loop through the numbers. It is correct when it used singularly, so the problem is my lookup system. I'm pretty sure I don't understand how to look for a value in a dictionary. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Not for all numbers, try `100`, it returns `117`

Comment: When I looped through 1 to 100, they all returned 1, including 100.

Comment: The problem is in the memoizing; when I loop through values, they return 1. When I just use the function singularly, they return correct values.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean in your code?

Comment: Sorry, should've said that in the OP. Didn't know that was the case at the time.

Comment: I'm trying to memoize divisor sums. For instance, for a large number, it must have a divisor that has already had it's own divisor sum calculated. So, instead of calculating that again, that value is saved, and when the bigger number is being computed, it reaches that value and just gets the sum from the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

The usual shortcut trick for memoize is to use a mutuable default argument

```
def sumDivisors(num, divisorSums={}):

    if num in divisorSums:          # Check if you have
        return divisorSums[num]     # memoized the answer here

    total = 0

    if num == 1:
        return 0

    for i in xrange(num/2, 0, -1):
        if not num % i:
            total += i

    divisorSums[num] = total

    return total
```

Other than that your code seems to work ok. How were you runnning it to get just `1`?

Comment: This code doesn't exactly memoize properly. See, when it's looping, it doesn't look for values in divisorSums.

Comment: @Tetramputechture, I see what you're saying. The memoize is ok, but where you were peeking in the divisorSums dict, it's better to just call the function recursively. Unfortunately I haven't got time to write up that version right now

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
if i in divisorSums:
            return divisorSums[i]
```

returning divisorSums[i] is not the right thing to do as there may be some prime factors less than `i`. Here is one way using a helper function to remember/calculate factors of numbers:

```
from itertools import groupby
divisorC={}
def divisors(num):
    if num in divisorC:
        return divisorC[num]
    l = {1:1}
    for i in xrange(num/2, 1, -1):
        if num % i == 0:
            l[i] = 1 
            l.update(divisors(i))
            l.update(divisors(num/i))
            break
    divisorC[num] = l 
    return divisorC[num]
def sumDivisors(num):
    if num == 1: return 0
    l = {}
    for i in xrange(num/2, 0, -1):
        if num % i == 0:
            l.update(divisors(i))
            l.update(divisors(num/i))
            l[i] = 1 
            l[num/i] = 1 
            break
    return sum(v for v in l)
```

Comment: When I run this, it returns the sum of divisors of 6 as 4, when it should be 6. Hmm.

Comment: Woah that's a pretty big change